# Internet Explorer & Edge Skrollr Jumping after so many px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, skrollr

Got a bit of a bug on a parallax site that maybe someone could help with:

http://theworkstimeline.theworksdev.co.uk/

Parallax scrolling using Skrollr https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Once you scroll down to around the halloween section the scenes start bouncing around... I've looked into this for a long time now and can't seem to suss it out!

Not entirely sure how the rest of the scenes are working and then suddently stop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the answer was for anyone that might stumble across this, I had to display none and display block the scenes as they left / entered the viewport... Bizarre!

If anyone can shed light on why this might have fixed it that would be great!